# Getting the app onto the phone... certificate signing and identities

Tags: iphone, certificate, identity, provisioning

The error I received on build attempt was:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks // :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a paid up developer ?
Have you created a provisioning profile for your application ?
Have you installed a provisioning profile via the Organizer?

if you have, then you need to go to the KeyChain utility, ensure that Login is the default Keychain, and that iPhone Developer:yournamehere certificate is installed along with the public and private keys of your dev certificate.

if you haven't, then you need to follow the steps in the provisioning utility http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action

Answer (score 0):

This took me about 3 hours to figure out but I found that when you send the request for the certificate, if you have multiple profiles on your computer you might have to request it from your name from the keys in KeyChain Access... just doing it from the drop down menu wasn't binding the certificate to the private key...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds stupid simple, but it worked for me:

Restart your Mac

I know, what is this, Windows?  But really, I just upgraded xcode 3.2.5 with ios 4.2 and same problem running new xcode.  After banging my head around a bit, just restarted my Mac, came back into xcode, and bingo!

Hope its that easy for everyone ;)